# Conway's Soldiers

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

I've been working on a modification to the standard Conway's soldiers game. In 
Conway's soldiers, we have an endless number of soldiers in a grid of squares 
at and below point 0 North, and I can move soldiers left, right, up, and down 
by having them jump over other soldiers, which makes those "jumped over" 
soldiers get removed from the board. The key thing is, I can only move soldiers 
by having said soldiers jump over each other, and thus it becomes a challenge to
 see in an extremal manner how likely it is to advance a soldier a certain 
number of squares north. I have a feeling that if I were to implement this game 
such that soldiers can jump diagonally, The number of moves it takes to move 9 
squares north approaches infinity. I'm having some issue formalizing this idea. 
Is there a way I can model this problem using some form of potential function? 
I've seen them used in similar applications towards amortized analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In his Masters thesis "[Pegs, Pebbles, Pennies, and Piles - a study of some combinatorial games](https://people.kth.se/~niklase/publ/exjobb.pdf)", Niklas Eriksen proves that 9 cannot be reached. The proof does involve "some form of potential function" (Conway [calls them "Pagoda functions" in this case](http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?messageID=1072847&tstart=0)), but is too long to reproduce here.

In "[Diagonal Checker-jumping and Eulerian Numbers for Color-signed Permutations](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v7i1r3)" by Eriksen, Eriksson, and Eriksson, that proof is re-presented and it is mentioned that 8 definitely *can* be reached.

Incidentally, these papers contain results about higher dimensions as well. But unlike 1 and 2 dimensions, these are only bounds on what can be reached. The known unreachable levels in the first several dimensions are $2,9,18,28,40,51,64$. But I don't know if anyone's been able to reach, say, level $17$ in 3 dimensions.